# How to construct material implications/conditionals?

Tags: logic

I am trying to understand how material conditionals can be constructed from a single given statement, but I do not know how to do it.

For example; if I have a statement such as "It rains" and I want to know what antecedents and consequents there could be to construct conditionals. How can I find out?

Comment: [Material Conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) in propositional logic formalizes statements of form: "if..., then...".

Comment: A statement like "it rains" has not that form: thus, you cannot use material conditional.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but i want to create material conditionals given the statement, one way would be to guess other statements that it might imply?

Comment: You can use as *antecedent* "if it rains, than I'll go to school", and as *consequent*: "if the sun shine, then it rains".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA - I don't think the material conditional can really be said to formalize the "if-then" of ordinary language, see the SEP article about [indicative conditionals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicative_conditional) in language and how they clearly aren't the same thing as the material conditional. The material conditional P->Q is equivalent to the idea that one or both of the statements "Q is true" or "P is false" must be true, but in ordinary language most people wouldn't judge a statement like "if the earth is flat, then zebras have stripes" to be true.